# JSF 2.0 Pass parameters to the same page

Tags: java, jsf, parameter-passing, managed-bean

i have a page called page1.jsf which contains one parameter.  i have a command button which contains the param.  On clicking the button, it must return to page1.jsf together with whatever parameter i pass.

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.DoSthng}" value="Something" >
 <f:param name="p1" value="sthng"></f:param>
 </h:commandButton>
```

How would i pass this parameter to page1.jsf itself?

In the faces-config.xml - managed Bean, i set it like this

```
<managed-bean>
  <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
  <managed-bean-class>com.MyBean</managed-bean-class>
  <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  <managed-property>
    <property-name>p1</property-name>
    <value>#{myBean.p1}</value>
  </managed-property>
</managed-bean>
```

and this is giving me an error.

Can you all help me please.

**EDIT**

From page1 i have to pass a value from an action to backing bean.  The backing bean should redirect me back to page1 but with different contents!

Comment: could you please explain `pass this parameter to page1.jsf itself?`

Comment: @JigarJoshi edited question, plz check again

Comment: Still its not clear, Do you mean passing parameter like `page1.jsf?param=val` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put your param in hidden field and it will be available

```
<input type="hidden" id="sl" name="sl" value="#{param.sl}"/>
```

And then you can use it

```
${param.sl}
```

Comment: didnt use hidden field, just used $(param.s1).. its working, thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve, you could use an `f:setPropertyActionListener`:

```
<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.DoSthng}" value="Something" >
   <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{myBean.p1}" value="something" />
</h:commandButton>
```

This will set the backing bean property and if you return null from your action method (or if it is void) the current page should reflect the changes made to your backing bean.

Answer (score 0):

From page you are calling an `action` so while returning you could do following

```
return "someView.jsf?param=val&faces-redirect=true"
```

Comment: well you want to access parameter on page or you want to pass parameter to page from action ?